# Muting the sound by half in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio

I have a problem with the sound in my game in unity. The thing is that when I export my application for example to android all sounds are muted by more than half , and on the computer in unity everything works fine. not sure what this could depend on. I have the sound source on max and the general sound settings are also on max.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the music sound volume to 1. Either in inspector on the audio source object or in code like this:

```
audiosource.volume = 1f;
```